# Error viewing images after enabling HHVM

Tags: magento, hhvm

I need some help with HHVM on Magento. I just enabled HHVM for my site but I am not able to see any images. It shows only the placeholder image for thumbnail, category and product details page. This happens for the backend and the frontend. Some category images are visible but as soon as I delete the cache, it does not get regenerated. They all disappear for good.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a Magento issue vs. some other HHVM/nginx issue? For example, if you have a simple "hello world"-type site, e.g., some PHP that generates a page with text and an image, does that work?

Comment: The homepage has static images and that seems to work with no problem. It is the inside pages. The category and sub category page show images as long as I do not clear the cache. As soon as I clear the cache is all gone. It seems that it is now allowing Cache images to be created. Please let m know if that give you a better clue to the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem we had where the image disappeared when we enabled HHVM from control Panel. The problem is the memory limit in the .INI file was -1 and magneto GD2.php does not recognize -1 value in memory check function in GD2.php as in the code below (LINE 83 - 89):

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
  return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
} elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
  return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
}
```

SOLUTION:
I added the following code below it and created a local version of GD2.php. Everything now seems to work fine.

```
elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'G') !== false) {
  return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
}
elseif (trim($memoryValue) == '-1') {
  return 14589934592;
}
```